# Using Map as an in-memory cache in Spring with TTL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I'm implementing an authorization logic with passwordless login.

In order to log in to the system a client must:

1. send **GET** `/auth/challenge` request along with their username
2. get response from the above request which contains some encyption, do magic and send **POST** `/auth/verify` request with generated secret and (hopefully) get logged in

Right now I'm thinking about ways to ensure that `/auth/verify` is called right after `/auth/challenge` and not in say 1-2 days after `/auth/challenge` was made.

So, when `/auth/challenge` is performed, a large random prime is generated and then encoded and sent along with some other stuff. When it's generated on the server-side I can save it with a current timestamp and perform validation on expiration when second request is sent, but that seems as too much unneeded interactions with a db.  Saving encoded primes to some map with ttl seems like a more elegant approach, but in this case there's a need of removing old map entries which right now I can imagine only in a for of some `@Scheduler` which would remove "expired" primes.

Whould it be efficient to store encoded primes like this, or is there any other more request-oriented way of doing this?

Comment: Instead of a random number: Maybe better generate a timestamp, concatenate it with a local secret and hash it. When a request comes back you can verify that the challenge was from you and you have the timestamp. You don't need to store anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use Redis (key-value) database for it. You could set expire key property like here:

> Set a timeout on key. After the timeout has expired, the key will
> automatically be deleted.